# using Linux vncviewer

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, wine

when i am connecting to VNC server using wine on linux

> $ wine vncviewer.exe

i have to enter:

> VNC Server: 1.1.1.21
>
> Proxy/Reapeter: 195.29.18.33:1234

and then, when i connect, on top there is txt:
1.1.1.21:5900 (195.29.18.33:1234)

mine question is: how to connect using vncviewer ?

what to put in VNC_VIA_CMD ?

> $ export xlocalPort=1234
>
> $ export xremoteHost=1.1.1.21
>
> $ export xremotePort=5900
>
> $ export xgateway=195.29.18.33
>
> $ export VNC_VIA_CMD="/usr/bin/ssh -f -L $xlocalPort:$xremoteHost:$xremotePort $xgateway sleep 20"
>
> $ vncviewer $xremoteHost -via $xgateway

and i get error:

> unable connect to socket: Connection refused (111)

i was trying to help myself with page

http://www.tightvnc.com/vncviewer.1.php

Please help, couse i need to use "native" linux vncviewer installed by

> $ yum install tigervnc
>
> tigervnc.i686 0:1.0.90-0.13.20100420svn4030.fc13

Comment: This is not programming related and will thus be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @San Jacinto: Actually this is a question on using user software, so it will likely be migrated to Super User. @Darkoni: See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) (linked at the top of the page for site selection advice. However, please to not re-post this question, it will e moved by a quorum of high rep users. Probably pretty soon.

Comment: Why are you running a vnc client under Wine ??

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run a Windows VNC client under WINE, there are compatible Linux VNC clients, too. [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/download.html) is one example, which installs as "Xvnc4" I believe.